# Multiple mediators and interaction effects- causal mediation effect

Tags: causality, mediation

Assume we have a structural equation system with treatment $T,$ mediator
$1$ (discrete) and mediator $2$ (continuous). We write this as:
$$
Y=\beta_{0}+\beta_{1}M_{1}+\beta_{2}M_{2}+\beta_{3}TM_{2}+\beta_{3}T+\epsilon
$$
$$
M_{1}=\alpha+\alpha_{1}T+v
$$
$$
M_{2}=\gamma+\gamma_{1}T+e
$$

For $M_{1},$ the causal mediation effect is easy to obtain- $\alpha_{1}\beta_{1}.$
However, given that we have an interaction effect with $M_{2}$, would
the causal mediation effect be:
$$
\gamma_{1}\beta_{2}+\gamma_{1}\beta_{3}M_{2}
$$

If this is the case, would a ``reasonable'' estimate of the causal
mediation effect be:
$$
\gamma_{1}\beta_{2}+\gamma_{1}\beta_{3}\mathbb{E}\left[M_{2}\right]
$$
where we take the average value of $M_{2}?$

Comment: Are you assuming each error ($\epsilon, v, e$) is independent?

Comment: Yes @Ben, these are indeed independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An important first step of an analysis is define the estimand, or estimation target. When you write, "causal mediation effect", the estimand is left ambiguous. There are several possible terms you could be describing. I'll take you to mean the indirect natural effect.

For convenience, this answer will use counterfactual notation, with an asterisk denoting a counterfactual. With a single mediator, this is defined as $$\mathbb{E}[Y_{t, M_{1}^*}^* - Y_{t, M_{0}^*}^*],$$ for a possible treatment value $t$. It is interpreted as giving the causal effect of the treatment that flows through a mediator $M$ when the treatment is held at $t$ (to block the direct effect).

Your problem has multiple mediators, but their analysis is simplified because neither is a descendant of the other. Thus we can study the effect of each mediator on its own.

For the first mediator, the indirect natural effect is
\begin{align*}
 & \mathbb{E}[Y_{t, M_{1,1}^*}^* - Y_{t, M_{1,0}^*}^*] \\
=\, &  \mathbb{E} \left[ \{\beta_0 + \beta_1(\alpha + \alpha_1 + v) + \beta_2M_2 + \beta_3tM_2 + \beta_4t + \epsilon\} - \\ \{\beta_0 + \beta_1(\alpha + v) + \beta_2M_2 + \beta_3tM_2 + \beta_4t + \epsilon\} \right] \\
=\, & \beta_1\alpha_1,
\end{align*}
for any $t$. This is the value you described.

For the second mediator, the indirect natural effect is
\begin{align*}
 & \mathbb{E}[Y_{t, M_{2,1}^*}^* - Y_{t, M_{2,0}^*}^*] \\
=\, &  \mathbb{E} \left[ \{\beta_0 + \beta_1 M_1 + \beta_2(\gamma + \gamma_1 + e) + \beta_3t(\gamma + \gamma_1 + e)+ \beta_4t + \epsilon\} - \\ \{\beta_0 + \beta_1M_1 + \beta_2(\gamma + e) + \beta_3t(\gamma + e) + \beta_4t + \epsilon\} \right] \\
=\, & \gamma_1 ( \beta_2 + \beta_3 t)
\end{align*}
for any $t$. Thus the natural indirect effect depends on the treatment value $t$. Holding the treatment at $t=0$ or at $t=1$ will lead to a different effect of the second mediator $M_2$.

Each indirect effect can be consistently estimated by plugging in a consistent estimator of the regression coefficients.

Comment: thank you. For the second mediator, as the effect depends on T, the reason I have the expectation is because I wanted a measure of an "average" effect. In that case, could the average effect in fact be written as what I have written?

Comment: @ChinG You can't -- you've written the term as depending on $m_2$, but the answer shows it actually depends on $t$. You certainly could average the natural indirect effect over the marginal distribution of the treatment $T$, although I think that would complicate the interpretation.

Comment: Ah yes. Got it! The treatment is continuous. This sounds like what I need. I have also asked other mediator-related questions which are bountied. Please feel free to answer them as well!!!

Comment: one more clarification. You mentioned that  the indirect effect is "It is interpreted as giving the causal effect of the treatment that flows through a mediator M,  when the treatment is held at t (to block the direct effect)". I am not sure how this would happen- if T is held at t, then the mediator would not change, correct? How can you hold T constant, while still varying the mediator?

Comment: @ChinG You could ask the same question about the direct effect, which is the part of the causal effect that does not flow through the mediators. The point is that neither the direct effect or the natural indirect effect are the total causal effect: they are a partition of the total causal effect, giving the parts explained by each variable.

Comment: Hmmm I see. Intuitively, I would say, insert the equation for M1 in the full equation, I would then take the derivative of Y with respect to T, and get the full effect of T (one direct, and one through M). But, doing that for M2, I get what I had obtained, and not what you had obtained.  It's just strange to me that we are varying T from 0 to 1 for the mediating equation, but not for the whole model. Marginal effects are generally not computed that way in other settings.

Comment: @ChinG I'm not sure why you're doing this procedure with plugging in terms and taking derivatives. You should use the definitions of the indirect effect that have already been developed in the literature. (They have a clear interpretation.)

Comment: OK, fair enough. Thanks! In one of my other bountied questions, I ask how the standard errors of the indirect effect (which is a product of coefficients) is computed. Please have a look at it if possible!! Would really appreciate it.

Comment: Finally- I was wondering if there is a need to standardize variables, specifically M_1 and M_2, in order to have comparable coefficients? As the data stand, the coefficients are in units of y/x, which depend on the units of x as well...

Comment: @ChinG I think this may be best asked as a stand-alone question